# Format of the bytes read through AudioSystem.read()

Tags: java, audio

I want to know the format of the bytes returned from `TargetDataLine.read()`. I get numbers but I don't know what they represent. Any idea? I've Googled to try and find out and read the API documentation but can't work it out...

Comment: Please be more specific which method call you are referencing, e.g. link to the JavaDoc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please specify what you have done so far to answer your question. What kind of library do you use?

Comment: I use the standard Java library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the bit-depth and encoding of the audio stream you're trying to read from. Assuming each data stream represents a single channel of audio then there won't be interleaved channels to worry about (i.e. the stream is mono rather than stereo or surround sound). The audio format of the object whose class implements `TargetDataLine` will determine how the data should be interpreted when read.

If the stream represents audio in the most common audio format, which is Red Book Audio (16-bit samples at a sample rate of 44.1 kHz), then every two bytes will represent a sample; that sample will be a signed 16-bit integer of linearly-distributed amplitude values ranging from positive-displacement 0 dBFS (maximum positive integer value), through negative infinity decibels (integer value 0) to negative-displacement 0 dBFS (maximum negative integer value). Similarly, if the bit-depth is 24-bits then every 3 bytes will represent a single LPCM sample.

If the bit-depth is 32-bit or higher then the format will be signed floating-point PCM samples.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I wanted To know. Sorry for the Bad question. Even in my own language i didnt knew how Tod describe my Problem right

Comment: No worries, @Victor, it was a valid question - I understood what you were asking, I just edited so other people could benefit from the extra clarity if they had the same query in future. If you could mark my answer as _accepted_ I would be grateful.

Comment: could you message me, if you have a link for understanding The dbfs unit better ?

Comment: @Victor, sure, although decibels (dB) are the unit, dBFS is just an abbreviation of "decibels relative to (digital, in this case) full scale", in other words the maximum amplitude value that can be represented. Decibels themselves are a logarithmic unit, i.e. they're not linearly distributed; the numbers you get from the samples will be linear amplitude values. Here are some Wikis I recommend you read: [dBFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS), [Decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel), [Pulse-code modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation)

Comment: So if I have an value of 0 I would write into a diagramm it gots the value -32767 dBFS ? (But I would set it to the Y=0) (Audio data with 16 Bit)